# Textures openGl. C++, qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm trying to cover my terrain(which is made from heightmap) with a grass texture, but it's not working as it should. I can't even get the texture on a simple GL_QUAD, the result is multicolor net.

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
//
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//
}
```

in QGLwidget I call

```
openTextureImg();
```

code of openTextureImg():

```
bool GLWidget::openTextureImg()
{

QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Image"),QDir::homePath(), tr("Image Files (*.png *.tga *.bmp)"));
QImage textureImg;

if (!fileName.isEmpty())
{


    textureImg = QImage(fileName, "PNG");
    qDebug()<<"image loaded";

    textureImg = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat( textureImg );
    glGenTextures( 1, &texHandle );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texHandle );

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, textureImg.width(), textureImg.height(), 0, GL_RGB,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureImg.bits());
    //glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );

    return true;
}
return false;


}
```

Here I'm trying to draw a quad:

```
   void GLWidget::drawRect()
{
    glColor3f(0.5,0.5,1.0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texHandle);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(0.0,0.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(1000.0,0.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(1000.0,1000.0);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(0.0,1000.0);



    glEnd();

}
```

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> `QImage QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat ( const QImage & img )   [static]`
>
> Converts the image img into the unnamed format expected by OpenGL functions such as glTexImage2D(). The returned image is not usable as a QImage, but QImage::width(), QImage::height() and QImage::bits() may be used with OpenGL. The GL format used is **GL_RGBA** [emphasis mine].

In your call to `glTexImage2D` use `GL_RGBA` instead of `GL_RGB`.