# QtOpenGL Load obj format with QImage texture

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

OBJ loading is OK, but texture loading fails. where did I do wrong?

in Model.h

```
#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H

#include <QVector>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QVector3D>
#include <QVector2D>
#include <QtOpenGL>

/* one texture only */

struct Face{
    QVector<QVector3D> v;
    QVector<QVector3D> vn;
    QVector<QVector2D> t;
    Face(){
        v.resize(3);
        vn.resize(3);
        t.resize(3);
    }
};

class Model
{
public:
    Model() {}
    Model(QString filename);
    void render();

    int faces() const { return Faces.size(); }
    int points() const { return Vertices.size(); }

private:
    QString fileName;
    QString textureName;
    QVector<QVector3D> Vertices; //v
    QVector<QVector3D> VNormals; //vn
    QVector<QVector2D> UVs;      //vt
    QVector<Face>      Faces;    //f
    GLuint texture;
    QImage textureImg;
    void LoadMTL(QString fn, QString MTLname);
    void LoadTexture();
};

#endif
```

in Model.cpp

```
#include "Model.h"

Model::Model(QString filename)
{
    fileName = filename;
    QString textruename;
    QVector3D temp3D;
    QVector2D temp2D;
    if(!fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        QFile file(fileName);
        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        {
            QTextStream fileText(&file);
            while (!fileText.atEnd())
            {
                QString fileLine = fileText.readLine();
                if(fileLine.startsWith("vn "))
                {
                    QStringList lineList = fileLine.split(" ");
                    temp3D.setX( lineList[1].toFloat() );
                    temp3D.setY( lineList[2].toFloat() );
                    temp3D.setZ( lineList[3].toFloat() );
                    VNormals.push_back(temp3D);
                }
                else if(fileLine.startsWith("vt "))
                {
                    QStringList lineList = fileLine.split(" ");
                    temp2D.setX( lineList[1].toFloat() );
                    temp2D.setY( lineList[2].toFloat() );
                    UVs.push_back(temp2D);
                }
                else if(fileLine.startsWith("v "))
                {
                    QStringList lineList = fileLine.split(" ");
                    temp3D.setX( lineList[1].toFloat() );
                    temp3D.setY( lineList[2].toFloat() );
                    temp3D.setZ( lineList[3].toFloat() );
                    Vertices.push_back(temp3D);
                }
                else if(fileLine.startsWith("f "))
                {
                    Face F;
                    QStringList lineList = fileLine.split(" ");

                    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                    {
                        QStringList arg = lineList[i].split("/");
                        F.v[i-1] = Vertices[arg[0].toInt()-1];
                        F.t[i-1] = UVs[arg[1].toInt()-1];
                        F.vn[i-1] = VNormals[arg[2].toInt()-1];
                    }
                    Faces.push_back(F);
                }
                else if(fileLine.startsWith("mtllib "))
                {
                    QStringList lineList = fileLine.split(" ");
                    textruename = lineList[1];
                }
            }
        }
        file.close();
        QFileInfo fi(fileName);
        QString BaseName = fi.fileName();
        QString fn(fileName);
        fn.remove(fn.size() - BaseName.size(), BaseName.size());
        LoadMTL(fn, fn + textruename);
    }
}

void Model::render()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glPushMatrix();
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        for(int i = 0; i < Faces.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                glNormal3f(Faces[i].vn[j].x(), Faces[i].vn[j].y(), Faces[i].vn[j].z());
                glTexCoord2f(Faces[i].t[j].x(), Faces[i].t[j].y());
                glVertex3f(Faces[i].v[j].x(), Faces[i].v[j].y(), Faces[i].v[j].z());
            }
        }
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
}

void Model::LoadMTL(QString fn, QString MTLname)
{
    if(!MTLname.isEmpty())
    {
        QFile file(MTLname);
        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        {
            QTextStream fileText(&file);
            while (!fileText.atEnd())
            {
                QString fileLine = fileText.readLine();
                if(fileLine.startsWith("map_Kd "))
                {
                    QStringList lineList = fileLine.split(" ");
                    textureName = fn + lineList[1];
                    LoadTexture();
                }
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
}

void Model::LoadTexture()
{
    textureImg = QImage(textureName);

    textureImg = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat( textureImg );
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textureImg.width(), textureImg.height(), 0, GL_RGBA,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureImg.bits());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
}
```

When I do

```
OBJ = new Model("C:/Users/username/Desktop/OBJ.obj");
OBJ->render();
```

It seems Model::LoadTexture() doesn't work.

I have seen this POST, but texture was not loaded.

[Textures openGl. C++, qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061016/textures-opengl-c-qt)

Please don't recommend any library which can load 3D format.

Comment: Is the texture loading code called with the target OpenGL context being active?

Comment: I'm not sure what did you mean, is there any example? Thanks.

Comment: Before you can make use of OpenGL you need a valid OpenGL context created and made active. In case of QGLWidget this is only the case in either the `…GL` methods (initializeGL, paintGL) or after calling makeCurrent (must be countered with a call of doneCurrent).

Comment: [this](http://i.imgur.com/lX0HrH6.png) is what I am doing. As you can see, the monkey has no texture on it. I think that valid OpenGL context has been created.

Comment: Can you please show the code where you actually create the instance of the model, i.e. from where the model loading is done.

Comment: Thank you!!! I just moved OBJ = new Model("C:/Users/username/Desktop/OBJ.obj"); from constructor to initializeGL() and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, and rollback your edit to  your question. We like to keep Qs and As separate here (and don't like markers in titles at all).

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM HAS SOLVED :

white

```
OBJ = new Model("C:/Users/username/Desktop/OBJ.obj");
```

into initializeGL() instead of constructor.

Thanks to datenwolf !!